# How to prevent Linux Mint going to sleep while Samba sharing is active?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, sleep, samba, suspend

My desktop is configured to go to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity. I'm sharing movies from it's hard drive to home network with Samba. Problem is that it suspends after 30 minutes although I'm streaming a movie on my home network. Apparently, Samba sharing is not registered as an activity. How can I make it see that Samba share in in progress and postpone suspend? OS is Linux Mint.

Comment: Try this program https://launchpad.net/keep.awake
It will keep your desktop awake based on either user-activity (keyboard, mouse), or cpu-activity, or network-activity (your samba sharing).
I wrote it for Ubuntu but should work with Mint as long as you satisfy the dependencies.
Let me know how you go if you do try it out.  Cheers...

Comment: @DanglingPointer: Doesn’t work on Linux. Only works on PoetteringOS/Gnome/Mutter.

Answer (score 1):

**Caffeine** is a utility available in the package manager that serves a similar function as the scripts.  It periodically injects meaningless keyboard activity so the system doesn't appear as idle.  Caffeine sticks an icon in the system tray that you can toggle on and off, which is convenient.  The publisher's description refers to it working when in full-screen mode.  When I last used it, I don't think it required full-screen mode.  But worst case, make the application full-screen in that workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I did it! I'll explain how, maybe it will help others.

Install xdotool

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then, make a script in /usr/local/bin/

```
sudo xed /usr/local/bin/checksmb.sh
```

Copy this to xed:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/sinisab89/.Xauthority 

if [ `sudo smbstatus | grep DENY | wc -l` != 0 ]
then
xdotool key F9
exit 0
fi
```

Save file.

DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY is needed for CRON to function properly. smbstatus only runs with sudo. I chose F9 key, maybe there are better options.
Script reads smbstatus and if there are more than 0 "DENY" entries in the report (active connections in Samba) simulates F9 key press which resets system idle timer and prevents suspend. If there are 0 "DENY" entries script does nothing.

Make checksmb.sh executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/checksmb.sh
```

Now set up CRON to execute script every x minutes. I chose 20 minutes.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Scroll to the bottom and add

```
*/20 * * * * /usr/local/bin/checksmb.sh >> /home/YOUR USERNAME/cron.log 2>&1
```

/home/YOUR USERNAME/cron.log 2>&1 makes a cron.log file in your home folder. You can use it for troubleshooting if the script is not executed properly.

With this command you can see if CRON is executing script at given time

```
less /var/log/syslog | grep checksmb
```

This is not the most elegant solution but it works. If someone knows how, for example, video players prevent system from sleeping it would be nice to modify this script so it doesn't use xdotool. There has to be some system suspend inhibitor but I just couldn't find anything online.

I think Caffeine requires user input and doesn't run automatically. Sry I'm replying as this but it doesn't allow me to comment...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with this script, run by Cron with a time interval close to the power management's suspend settings.

```
$ crontab -e
*/10 * * * * $HOME/.local/bin/suppress-suspension.sh
```

Script content:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority

ALLOW_IDLE=250000

if [ "$(xprintidle)" -gt $ALLOW_IDLE ]; then
    if [ "$(sudo smbstatus | grep --count DENY)" -gt 0 ] ||
    [ "$(pgrep --count rclone)" -gt 0 ]; then
        eval "$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)"
        xdotool mousemove "$X" "$Y"
        exit 0
    fi
fi
```

`ALLOW_IDLE` - IDLE threshold in milliseconds above which subsequent script logic is executed, this value must be less than your screen/suspend timeout (in my example it is 4 min 10 sec).

`xprintidle` - tiny [cli tool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xprintidle.1.html) which returns user's IDLE time in miliseconds.

`sudo smbstatus | grep --count DENY` - just filter out lines with `DENY` in the output of the `smbstatus` command and count the number of those lines using the `--count` [option](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html#:%7E:text=Output%20Control%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2Dc%2C-,%2D%2Dcount,-Suppress%20normal%20output).

If the IDLE timeout has already exceeded the threshold and any paths blocked by the smb server have been detected, we simply [get the current mouse pointer coordinates](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html#:%7E:text=up%20is%20sent.-,getmouselocation,-%5B%2D%2Dshell%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Outputs) and store them in environment variables by calling with eval:

`eval "$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)"`

And finally, before exiting, make a fake mouse move to the same position:

`xdotool mousemove "$X" "$Y"`

This event resets the current IDLE timeout to 0, which prevents the system from suspending/screen turning off.

As you can see, I also extended the condition for this event by checking if the [rclone](https://rclone.org/) process is running to sync with the cloud storage, which I also don't want to interrupt:

`pgrep --count rclone`

In the same way, you can control any processes that should block the system from being suspended, just add more conditions:

```
...
[ "$(pgrep --count rclone)" -gt 0 ] ||
[ "$(pgrep --count foo)" -gt 0 ] ||
[ "$(pgrep --count bar)" -gt 0 ]; then
...
```

After all of the specified processes are completed, none of the conditions will return true and the system will be suspended according to your power management settings.

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Ubuntu – Prevent sleep while sharing files over samba](https://aikar.co/2011/03/03/ubuntu-prevent-sleep-samba/)
proposes a script that will prevent Ubuntu from sleeping while sharing files,
using the
[smbstatus command](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbstatus.1.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# sleep prevent command - "gnome-screensaver-command --poke" resets idle timer
PREVENTSLEEP='gnome-screensaver-command --poke'

# gnome-screensaver-command uses X11 which expects this ENV to be set
export DISPLAY=:0.0

smbstatus | grep -q "DENY_WRITE"
if [ $? == 0 ]; then $PREVENTSLEEP ; fi
```

The article proposes using crontab for the periodic execution of the script.

Comment: I'm trying that but it doesn't quite work. I don't have 'gnome-screensaver-command --poke' on Linux Mint. So I tried to modify it a little but I'm quite a noob for this:

#!/usr/bin/env bash

# sleep prevent command - "gnome-screensaver-command --poke" resets idle timer
PREVENTSLEEP= xdotool key a

# gnome-screensaver-command uses X11 which expects this ENV to be set
export DISPLAY=:0.0

#### DO NOT EDIT ####
smbstatus | grep -q "DENY_NONE"
if [ $? == 0 ]; then $PREVENTSLEEP ; fi

This doesn't work as expected. No matter what smbstatus is it always runs xdotool command.

Answer (score 0):

*(Since all the other answers were hackish, too specialized, or limited to specific/outdated desktop software…)*

Here’s a very simple one-liner that does the job in a generic way, by treating network interaction just like keyboard interaction. So the inactivity timeout settings of your environment can still be used.

```bash
    shopt -s extglob; sum="$( cat /sys/class/net/!(lo|vir*)/statistics/*_bytes | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' )"; if [[ "$sum" -gt "$(cat /tmp/network-activity.last_bytes)" ]]; then echo "$sum" > /tmp/network-activity.last_bytes; kbd="$(ls /dev/input/by-path/*-kbd | head -n 1)"; evemu-event "$kbd" --type EV_KEY --code KEY_SLEEP --value 1 --sync; evemu-event "$kbd" --type EV_KEY --code KEY_SLEEP --value 0 --sync; fi
```

Or, in human-readable form:

```bash
    shopt -s extglob # To be able to filter loopback and virtual NICs.
    sum="$( cat /sys/class/net/!(lo|vir*)/statistics/*_bytes | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' )" # Total transferred bytes
    if [[ "$sum" -gt "$(cat /tmp/network-activity.last_bytes)" ]]; then # Was something transferred since the last time?
        echo "$sum" > /tmp/network-activity.last_bytes # Remember
        kbd="$(ls /dev/input/by-path/*-kbd | head -n 1)" # find first keyboard
        evemu-event "$kbd" --type EV_KEY --code KEY_WAKEUP --value 1 --sync # Press WAKEUP key
        evemu-event "$kbd" --type EV_KEY --code KEY_WAKEUP --value 0 --sync # Release again
    fi
```

Put it in your crontab or in a script to be run from crontab, to execute once a minute, and you’re good.

All it needs, is `evemu-tools`, `awk` and `bash`. (Translating it for another shell should be easy. And `awk` is only used to sum all the network bytes.)
Make sure it is run as `root`, to have access to the event device files.
`evemu-tools` is nice, in that it is completely software agnostic. It literally just sends input events as if they came from the hardware. Conveniently, it uses the `WAKEUP` key, which should never trigger or be mapped in software on a normal system, but be sure it’s not mapped to something, or change it.

Comment: Note that *-kbd might include programmable mice too, but even if they do not offer a KEY_WAKEUP, I found it to work. You can test it by replacing it by KEY_SLEEP and watching it go to sleep.

Comment: Additional feature: Filter out small irrelevant traffic, because some devices just can’t shut up: Replace `$sum` with `$(( sum + bytesToIgnore ))` in the `if` statement, where `bytesToIgnore` is some number.